# Image is not displaying despite being set in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following setup to display three columns, the middle column contains an image which to my knowledge has been correctly configured:

```
class StartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 24, right: 24),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: DropdownRow(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/home_icon.png',
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  )),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0),
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                        text: "I am a", style: Styles.h4BlackTextStyle),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have also configured pubspec.yml as follows. The indentation is also correct:

```
   assets:
    - assets/images
```

[image]

Finally I have the image inside the images folder in assets as follows:

[image]

But with this setup, the image does not show up on the actual app, see below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, do they show when you set width and height of the image simply to 100?

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that Flutter was caching my builds, after running the following command, and then doing a fresh build the image appears.

> flutter clean

Apparently making changes on the pubspec.yml file requires a clean build when the changes do not reflect

Answer (score 0):

in pubspec.yaml
`assets: - assets/images`

to    `assets: - assets/images/`
pub get then stop the app then run